# Create common dispatch function with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am pretty new to redux and here I am trying to create a common dispatch function where I can call the function from multiple components but can't seem to use `useDispatch()` in my common component getting invalid hook call error.

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { UPDATE_PREVIEW_DATA } from "../../redux/types";

export default function setPreviewData(event, obj, lang) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const previewData = useSelector((state) => state.previewData);

  const dispatchFunc = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PREVIEW_DATA,
      data: {
        [obj]: {
          [lang]: {
            ...previewData[obj][lang],
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
          },
        },
      },
    });
  };

  return dispatchFunc;

}
```

```js
// previewData.js in action folder

import { UPDATE_PREVIEW_DATA } from "../types";

const previewData = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_PREVIEW_DATA,
    data,
  });
};

export default previewData;
```

```js
// previewData.js in reducers folder

import { UPDATE_PREVIEW_DATA } from "../types";

const initialState = {...};

const previewData = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PREVIEW_DATA: {
      return action.data;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default previewData;
```

And I am trying to make this work like

```js
// component.jsx

setPreviewData(e, "hightlights", "en");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are intended to be used in Functional components only. As per the Rules of hooks they can be called from

- React function components.
- Custom Hooks

Reference -> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions

now you might think your setPreviewData is a React Function Component, but it's just a normal js function, that's why you are getting the error.
As a result, it doesn't get wrapped in React.createElement, so it thinks the hook call is invalid.

Moreover, you are committing one more mistake here, lets's say if setPreviewData was a Function Component you still call it as if though its a normal function